# Is it mandatory to create SVN repository in /var directory of Linux operating system

Tags: svn

Please explain where to create the repository in organizations if it is a Linux environment. Is it mandatory to create it in /var directory.

Answer (score 0):

Create where you want (approved by corporate policy), keep in mind only size of partition (repositories in long run|big team can get giant size)